# How to install Flowable designer in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, flowable

I am trying to install flowable designer in eclipse(kepler),but getting following errors. Please,give me solutions.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Flowable Eclipse BPMN 2.0 Designer 5.22.0 (org.flowable.designer.feature.feature.group 5.22.0)
  Missing requirement: Graphiti (Incubation) 0.13.1.v20160830-1309 (org.eclipse.graphiti 0.13.1.v20160830-1309) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.emf.transaction [1.8.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Graphiti (Incubation) 0.13.1.v20160830-1309 (org.eclipse.graphiti.feature.feature.group 0.13.1.v20160830-1309)
    To: org.eclipse.graphiti [0.13.1.v20160830-1309]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Flowable Eclipse BPMN 2.0 Designer 5.22.0 (org.flowable.designer.feature.feature.group 5.22.0)
    To: org.eclipse.graphiti.feature.feature.group [0.13.1.v20160830-1309]
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Help → Install New Software. In the following panel, click on Add button and fill in the following fields:

Name: Flowable BPMN 2.0 designer

Location: http://www.flowable.org/designer/update/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and error message when trying to install Flowable (both from repository URL and from Jar file).

In my case, when installing Eclipse I had reused my previous workspace.

Try installing Eclipse again with a totally fresh workspace, then adding Flowable - this approach worked for me.